# TSQL joins using more than one 'ON' keyword

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I came across a stored procedure that contained some syntax I found to be confusing to read. I am hoping someone can help to explain the multiple usage of the 'ON' keyword in JOINS (see the generalized example below). I am having trouble finding a clear answer and example as to why this approach would be used.

```
SELECT *
FROM rc rc 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN etc 
INNER JOIN CR cr 
INNER JOIN cre cre ON cr.x = cre.x 
INNER JOIN ca ca ON cr.ID = ca.ID ON etc.ETCID = cre.ETCID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN cred cred ON cre.CRID = cred.CRID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN SC SC ON cred.ID = SC.ID 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN ec ec ON cred.ID = ec.ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ecc ecc ON cred.ID = ecc.ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN hcc hcc ON cred.ID = hcc.ID ON rc.ID = cred.ID
```

Comment: You either transcribed the SQL statement incorrectly or this is not T-SQL. You can't write: `ON t2.ID = t3.ID ON t2.ID = t1.ID` as is not even valid. And I'd be surprised if is even valid on any other database management system.

Comment: There was probably a join without the on clause earlier in the query that your example has omitted. Like https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/125423/3690

Comment: My apologies, considering the comments, I instead copy/pasted the JOINS and removed the table and column names.

Comment: Thank you for the link to the other Q&A it seems this is just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the syntax of the `FROM` clause on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql). I've reproduced a couple of the relevant bits here:

```
[ FROM { <table_source> } [ ,...n ] ]

<table_source> ::=   
{  
    table_or_view_name [ [ AS ] table_alias ]   
        [ <tablesample_clause> ]   
        [ WITH ( < table_hint > [ [ , ]...n ] ) ]   
    | <some options omitted here>
    | <joined_table>   
    | <some more options omitted here>
}  

<joined_table> ::=   
{  
    <table_source> <join_type> <table_source> ON <search_condition>   
    | <some options omitted here>
}

<join_type> ::=   
[ { INNER | { { LEFT | RIGHT | FULL } [ OUTER ] } } [ <join_hint> ] ]  
JOIN
```

A few points relevant to the query in your original question:

1. The first form shown for `<joined_table>`—actually the only one I've shown—ends with an `ON` clause, and permits any `<table_source>` between its `<join_type>` and its `ON` clause.
2. `<joined_table>` by itself is a valid form of `<table_source>`.
3. It is therefore legal to nest one `<joined_table>` inside of another, in which case the `ON` clause of the inner `<joined_table>` will be immediately followed by the `ON` clause of the outer `<joined_table>`. I think that's what you're seeing in your query.

To verify that I could reproduce your result, I created the appropriate in-memory tables and substituted them into your original query to get:

```
declare @rc table (id bigint);
declare @etc table (etcid bigint);
declare @cr table (x bigint, id bigint);
declare @cre table (x bigint, etcid bigint, crid bigint);
declare @ca table (id bigint);
declare @cred table (crid bigint, id bigint);
declare @sc table (id bigint);
declare @ec table (id bigint);
declare @ecc table (id bigint);
declare @hcc table (id bigint);

SELECT *
FROM
    @rc rc 
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
        @etc etc/*added*/
        INNER JOIN
            @CR cr 
            INNER JOIN @cre cre
            ON cr.x = cre.x 
            INNER JOIN @ca ca
            ON cr.ID = ca.ID 
        ON etc.ETCID = cre.ETCID 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN @cred cred 
        ON cre.CRID = cred.CRID 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN @SC SC 
        ON cred.ID = SC.ID 
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN @ec ec 
        ON cred.ID = ec.ID 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN @ecc ecc 
        ON cred.ID = ecc.ID 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN @hcc hcc
        ON cred.ID = hcc.ID 
    ON rc.ID = cred.ID
```

There are only three differences between your original query and mine, and none of them should affect how it works:

1. I replaced your original table names with my equivalent in-memory table names.
2. I changed `etc` in the original query to `@etc etc`, giving an alias to the `@etc` table.
3. I changed the formatting so that each `ON` clause is positioned directly below the corresponding `JOIN`, to hopefully illustrate what goes with what.

Here's a screenshot from my editor with some additional visual aids: note that each of the large expressions outlined in blue satisfies the definition of `<joined_table>` given above. The green arrows match the oddly-placed `ON` clauses to their corresponding joins.

[image: Query illustration]

So yes, it is legal syntax, but no, I can't think of any reason why you'd actually want to do this. If you're going to join one group of tables to another, there are vastly-less-confusing alternatives available, such as a subquery or [common table expression](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: Excellent markup!  I believe this is done because that INNER JOIN right after the RIGHT OUTER JOIN effectively makes the RIGHT OUTER JOIN an INNER JOIN.  So you move the ON clause to the end and that lets the optimizer consider the OUTER JOIN last.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, `JOIN` not only joins tables or views, but also the result of other join operations. This causes the `ON` keyword to not directly follow the joined table name.

Brackets indicate joined join results:

```
SELECT *
FROM rc rc 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
[   etc 
    INNER JOIN CR 
    [   cr 
        INNER JOIN cre cre ON cr.x = cre.x 
        INNER JOIN ca ca ON cr.ID = ca.ID 
    ] ON etc.ETCID = cre.ETCID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN cred cred ON cre.CRID = cred.CRID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN SC SC ON cred.ID = SC.ID 
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN ec ec ON cred.ID = ec.ID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ecc ecc ON cred.ID = ecc.ID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN hcc hcc ON cred.ID = hcc.ID 
] ON rc.ID = cred.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Using On 1x and  use AND after is technically the same. There isn't a difference in the execution. Personally, I've never seen anyone write multiple ON

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 t3 ON t2.ID = t3.ID AND  t2.ID = t1.ID
```

Comment: You haven't seen it because it's not valid t-sql! You can't do `ON t2.ID = t3.ID ON t2.ID = t1.ID`

Comment: @BrienFoss It does not work. See my answer in a few seconds.

Answer (score -1):

You either transcribed the SQL statement incorrectly or this is not T-SQL. You can't write: `ON t2.ID = t3.ID ON t2.ID = t1.ID` as is not even valid. And I'd be surprised if is even valid on any other database management system.

What you can do, though, is something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 t3 ON t2.ID = t3.ID 
AND /*AND, NOT ON*/ 
t2.ID = t1.ID
```

In other words, you can do a JOIN forcing the match on multiple columns but you cannot do a JOIN the way you wrote it above.

Comment: Downvoting because it's demonstrably false: if you actually create all the tables referenced in the OP, you'll find that SQL Server *does* actually execute the query as written. I haven't untangled exactly how it does so yet, but somehow it's making sense of an admittedly very confusing syntax.

Comment: @JoeFarrell No, it doesn't execute it. It's not valid syntax. Read the BNF for T-SQL FFS!

Comment: @JoeFarrell this answer was written before the edit to the question. The original code in the Q was invalid as there must be exactly as many `on` clauses as joins and it had three on clauses and 2 joins. And regarding "untangling" see my link in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, @MartinSmith. I'll remove my downvote but leave my original comment.

Comment: Correct. I screwed it up by posting a variation to the problem thinking I was removing some of the unnecessary joins. Now I understand the other joins without ON clauses actually affected the whole picture, so I pasted all of the joined tables later on. My mistake.